# using zoom conference, clicking "Join" button on landing UI will popup a blank white window and then hangs

Tags: 18.04, zoom-meeting

I am using 18.04 with zoom conference, clicking "Join" button on landing UI will popup a blank white window and then hangs.

But from meeting tab, click on the same meeting "Join" button, it works.

log is provided.

```
~/.zoom/logs/zoom_stdout_stderr.log
qrc:/qml/UpComingMeeingItemDetailDelegate.qml:95: ReferenceError: meetingItemPointer is not defined
QCoreApplication::postEvent: Unexpected null receiver
QCoreApplication::postEvent: Unexpected null receiver
QCoreApplication::postEvent: Unexpected null receiver
QCoreApplication::postEvent: Unexpected null receiver
QCoreApplication::postEvent: Unexpected null receiver
WorkerBase::loop() normal exit, fds[0].revents & POLLIN = trueWorkerBase::loop() normal exit, fds[0].revents & POLLIN = trueWorkerBase::loop() normal exit, fds[0].revents & POLLIN = trueWorkerBase::loop() normal exit, fds[0].revents & POLLIN = trueCSBConfUI::OnConfStatusChanged UI_CMD_SHARE_READYQCoreApplication::postEvent: Unexpected null receiver
QCoreApplication::postEvent: Unexpected null receiver
QCoreApplication::postEvent: Unexpected null receiver
QCoreApplication::postEvent: Unexpected null receiver
WorkerBase::loop() normal exit, fds[0].revents & POLLIN = trueWorkerBase::loop() normal exit, fds[0].revents & POLLIN = trueWorkerBase::loop() normal exit, fds[0].revents & POLLIN = trueWorkerBase::loop() normal exit, fds[0].revents & POLLIN = trueqrc:/qml/UpComingMeeingItemDetailDelegate.qml:95: ReferenceError: meetingItemPointer is not defined
```

[OS] ubuntu 18.04

zoom conference landing UI "join" button:
[image: zoom conference landing UI "join" button]

zoom conference popup a blank white window and hangs:
[image: zoom conference popup a blank white window and hangs]

Comment: Hi all, I tested again, the problem relates to zoom client linux version 5.1.422789.0705 itself. I also tested an old one version 5.0.403652.0509 and the problem cannot be reproduced.

Comment: The version 5.2.440215.0803 is broken too